# how to stop body-parser from returning undefined in nodejs application

Tags: node.js

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var path = require('path');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json({type: 'application/json'});
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
app.use('*', cors());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/json'}));
app.use(cookieParser());
```

here is my client side code using jquery API

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/checkIfAdmin",
        type: 'GET',
        data: JSON.stringify({'password': 'password', 'username': 'username'}),
        crossDomain: true,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
               // doing something
        },
        error: function(data){
             // throw error here!
        }
});
```

Body parser has been returning an empty body, being trying to fix this now for a while, on app route below

```
app.get('/checkIfAdmin', jsonParser, function(req, res){
     console.log(req.body);
     // Am getting an empty object ie {}
});
```

am getting { } (empty object)
please how do I fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's get API. So, you will get the data in req.query.

Comment: seriously let my quickly try it out

Comment: for post you have to use req.body